# Extract sentences containing specific word(s)

Tags: r

I have a get_sentences (sentimentr) list, and need to extract only those sentences containing specific words.
This is how the data looks like:

```
> class(frasi_negative)
[1] "get_sentences"           "get_sentences_character" "list"                   
> frasi_negative[2:3]
[[1]]
[1] "Al mio cellulare (Xiaomi Redmi Note 5) si mostrano singolarmente, separate, quando cerco di connetterle."                                                   
[2] "O si connette alla destra, o alla sinistra, e in ogni caso il suono poi esce dalle casse del cellulare (nonostante aver dato alle cuffie tutti i permessi)."
[3] "Non capisco perché, data che la prima connessione era andata come si deve; spente e riaccese, hanno iniziato a comportarsi così."                           
[4] "Ho provato a riavviare sia loro che cellulare, a rimetterle nella scatoletta e ritoglierle, ma il problema persiste."                                       
[5] "Non penso c'entri il mio cellulare (mai avuto problemi con prodotti simili), in ogni caso effettuo reso con rimborso."                                      

[[2]]
[1] "Comprate due mesi fa."                                                                                                                               
[2] "All'inizio funzionavano perfettamente, ma dopo qualche settimana hanno iniziato a disconnettersi tra loro di tanto in tanto."                        
[3] "qualche giorno fa estraendo la sinistra dall'astuccio magnetico è saltata la saldatura che la teneva chiusa e questo è il risultato."                
[4] "Usandole in chiamata rendono un suono non limpido."                                                                                                  
[5] "Il suono è accettabile ma nulla di speciale."                                                                                                        
[6] "Ormai sono inutilizzabili."                                                                                                                          
[7] "Per il prezzo mi aspettavo un prodotto migliore e più duraturo (avendo già provato auricolari wireless della stessa fascia di prezzo di altri brand)"
```

As an example, if I search "wireless", only the [[2]][7] element should show up.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to iterate over the list using `lapply` and return the sentence which  matches a particular `keyword` using `grep` .

```
keyword <- 'wireless'
lapply(frasi_negative, function(x) grep(keyword, x, value = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
keyword <- 'wireless'
map(frasi_negative, ~  .x[str_detect(.x, keyword)])
```